# Insert formula with relative cell in a range

Tags: excel, vba, function

I've been searching how to insert a formula in a range where each cell refers to a different cell but I still have no clue on how to do it.

I've tried this:

```
Dim datejour As String
Dim datemois As String
Dim dateannee As String

datejour = Format(Day(Date), "00")
datemois = Format(Month(Date), "00")
dateannee = Year(Date)

lastrow2 = wsdata.range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
wsdata.range("E2:E" & lastrow2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SDM(D[0]" & "CALC" & dateannee & datemois & datejour & ")"
```

I basically want something like this:

| D | E |
| --- | --- |
| Marc | =SDM(D1CALC20220609) |
| Paul | =SDM(D2CALC20220609) |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "D1CALC20220609" represent?

Comment: SDM is a function which allows me to retrieve data, here D1 would be the cell D1, CALC would just be a name and the 20220609 would be the data of my file. Bcs my file name is CALC20220609.csv and it reads the value of D1 in this csv

Comment: Maybe `"=SDM(D & row() & "CALC" & dateannee & datemois & datejour & ")"`

Comment: Not working but thanks

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful feedback.